# XNA - ShowMissingRequirementsMessage() - What's missing?

Tags: xna, kinect-sdk

We have a fairly straightforward/simple game that is unfortunately causing an issue on a client's PC.

The exception from Event Viewer indicates missing requirements (see image)

[image]

I have read the following article, which describes what is required to deploy XNA games on other computers.  My game was built on XNA 4.0.

[what do i need to make xna framework games run on other computers?](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/1988.aspx)

I have ensured that the minimum requirements have been met (e.g. Windows OS, Direct X drivers, .NET Framework installations).

Upon digging further into `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` dll using Reflector, I can see that the game is throwing one of either exceptions: `NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException`, `NoAudioHardwareException`).

This is where I'm stuck - how do I determine what's causing these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the client PC does not meet the minimum hardware requirements for XNA 4.0.

What graphics card does the user have and what audio hardware?

XNA requires a minimum of DirectX compatible card with Shader Model 1.1 for instance.

Comment: Yes, I've checked both graphics device and audio, which meets the requirements.  I would like to drill down and figure out _exactly_ what caused the exception, but I'm not getting anywhere.